# opencv: check if two iplimages is equal to each other in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, c++11, opencv3.0

I want to check two Iplimage objects to see if the images they contain are identical. How could this be done in C/C++?

for example:

```
bool equal (Iplimage *source1, IplImage *source2) {
if (source1 == source2)
    return true;
return false;
}
```

Comment: You are only comparing the *pointers*, not what they are pointing to.

Comment: which OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: What does `equal` mean in your case? _Exactly per pixel_ equal or _equal in common sense_?

Comment: sorry, yes i mean pixel equal :)

Comment: i am using opencv 3.0

Comment: Unless you have some legacy code to mantain, you should use the C++ syntax, starting from using Mat over IplImage

Comment: please, you **must not** use IplImage* in the 1st place, but cv::Mat.

Comment: @berak Do you feel that Miki's comment here and those added to my answer are insufficient to impress upon the OP that the deprecated C API (and IplImage*) should not be used? I shall have to consider adding a more strongly worded warning to my answer. On a completely unrelated note, I'd like to celebrate receiving my first downvote ever! :D I shall always cherish it!

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using OpenCV 3.0 and C++, you can (and should) use `Mat`:

```
bool equal (Iplimage *source1, IplImage *source2) {
    cv::Mat mat1 = cv::cvarrToMat(source1);
    cv::Mat mat2 = cv::cvarrToMat(source2);
    cv::Mat D;
    absdiff(mat1, mat2, D);
    cv::Scalar s = sum(D);
    return s == cv::Scalar::all(0);
}
```

Update: I had to use the `cv::cvarrToMat` method found [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/23440/any-way-to-convert-iplimage-to-cvmat-in-opencv-300/) because the `Mat(IplImage)` constructor was removed in OpenCV 3.0. Yet one more reason to do away with IplImages completely.

This will work with images with 1, 3 or 4 channels, but the inputs must be of the same size, depth and number of channels. As @Miki points out in the comments, you can easily add checks for these conditions and return `false` if they aren't met.

Comment: You can return false (before absdiff) if size or channels are not equal

Comment: @Miki Correct, but I was trying to focus (perhaps incorrectly?) on the comparison rather than error checking.

Comment: I agree, was just to highlight (to OP)  the fact that you can easily extend this for more robust checks. Already +1

Comment: thanks for the code but it sayes that i can't convert ipl to mat and it give errors!

Comment: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:925:14: Candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'IplImage *' (aka '_IplImage *') to 'const cuda::GpuMat' for 1st argument

Comment: @shayarhashim Apparently they removed this constructor in OpenCV 3.0. I found [this alternative](http://answers.opencv.org/question/23440/any-way-to-convert-iplimage-to-cvmat-in-opencv-300/).

Comment: yap i saw that and tested it:

Comment: one: OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /Users/shayar/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 877
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/shayar/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:877: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat

Comment: bool equalimage (IplImage *source1, IplImage *source2) {
    imshow("test", cvarrToMat(&source1)) ;
    return 0;
}

Comment: @shayarhashim You don't need the `&`. I just tried and it's working; I'll update the code.

Comment: @shayarhashim Of course the best solution is to not user `IplImage` at all, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably since you did not ask a question, the example you give does not work. You must compare the content, and not the pointers. You can do it like this

```
#include <string.h>

bool equal (Iplimage *source1, IplImage *source2) {
    if (memcmp(source1, source2, sizeof(Iplimage)) == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help but i don't mean pointer or size equal! i mean if the pixels are equal!

Comment: My answer does not compare the pointers or the size. It compares the two structs. If these structs include pointers to pixel arrays, then you need to refine your question, show the struct definitions, and show what you have tried.

Comment: thanks for the code, but it just give me false always :\ also correct IplImage spell :)